# Combining commands and launching in a second terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

On macOS, I'm trying to run three commands (two in one terminal, and a second to launch in a new terminal after the first two complete).

This is what I'm currently using:
`grunt devUsingStagingData && npm start staging_data & grunt watch`

My goal is to keep the console logs from `npm start staging_data` and `grunt watch` separate. Is there anyway to launch `grunt watch` in a new terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want open -a . I don't have access to a mac right now to test so see this link for more detail on using the open command:
https://scriptingosx.com/2017/02/the-macos-open-command/

I believe the command you want would be

```
grunt devUsingStagingData && npm start staging_data & open -a "Terminal" "grunt watch"
```

That way the npm command is only started if devUsingStagingData works and then it will open a new terminal window in which it will execute grunt watch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).